# Vim match and matchadd do not appear to work the same

Tags: vim

I have been playing with the match functionality in vim (7.4) and am seeing some differences between match and matchadd that I cannot figure out.

The pattern I am using is a simple one to match some text at a specific line and column.

if I try the following it works and highlights the text:

```
:match Test /\%2l\%>4v\%<7v/
```

if I try the following it doesn't:

```
:call matchadd('Test','/\%2l\%>4v\%<7v/')
```

'Test' is here any highlight group.

a simpler pattern, however, works ok such as:

```
:call matchadd('Test','test')
```

Any explanation or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `/`'s from your regex. You do not need delimiters when using `matchadd()` or any vim function for that matter.

```
call matchadd('Test','\%2l\%>4v\%<7v')
```